# C++ Getting points between 2 points

Tags: c++

So I have 2 points where I want to get points in between them for smoother teleport travel.

```
POINT a; //Character Position
POINT b; //Some random map position
```

I was using this formula to get a middle point first, but I want to add more points of travel before reaching POINT b.

```
POINT midpoint(const POINT& a, const POINT& b) 
    {
        POINT ret;
        ret.x = (a.x + b.x) / 2;
        ret.y = (a.y + b.y) / 2;
        return ret;
    }
```

I thought I could just calculate middle points more frequently to get shorter positions but I was wondering if there was a more dynamic way of doing this instead of coding in several different middle points.

I don't want to keep doing this simple approach:

```
POINT middlepoint = midpoint(a, b);
POINT closerpoint = midpoint(a, middlepoint);
```

[How I want it to travel - number of points don't matter too much](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZCKG.png)

Comment: I _think_ (maybe) you're looking for [Bresenham's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: @PaulSanders: I walk through the circle extension as part of an interview process.

Comment: @Bathsheba I would fail :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all just using proportions.

```
void MakePoints( const POINT& a, const POINT& b, int n, std::vector<POINT> & pts )
{
    pts.clear();
    pts.push_back( a );
    int dx = b.x - a.x;
    int dy = b.y - a.y;
    for( int i = 1; i <= n, i++ )
    {
        pts.emplace_back( a.x + dx * i / n, a.y + dy * i / n );
    }
}
```

Comment: [`std::lerp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lerp) comes in handy here. Same result but cleaner code

Comment: Tim's answer is good.  I personally would have used a simpler function signature of `POINT path_point(const POINT & a, const POINT & b, float x)` and then said that `x` should travel from 0 to 1 as the object teleports from point a to point b.

Comment: Hmm, that's a more flexible solution, because it allows for non-integral proportions.

Comment: There are faster ways, see the first comment in the question.

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you. At least for my purpose, it was so fast that you can't even tell it's going to each point unlike the original method. I'll look at the other suggestions as well to experiment with. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

If your `POINT` class implements multiplication of a point by a `float` or `double`, and addition of two points (which are two handy operations to support), just make a `float` or `double` that changes from 0 to 1 over time, and do this:

```
float t = ...;  // changes from 0 to 1 over time
POINT intermediate = a * (1 - t) + b * t;
```